# CloudEnvironment getServiceInfo for Redis service results in Nullpointer

Tags: cloud-foundry

I am trying to deploy my Spring MVC app in CloudFoundry using a Redis service. I use Java Configuration where I call the Cloudfoundry CloudEnvironment getServiceInfo method for retrieving the instantiated Redis service. The app stages ok, but won't start giving a Nullpointer in the CF class:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.cloudfoundry.runtime.env.CloudEnvironment.getServiceInfo(CloudEnvironment.java:150)
```

I searched a lot for clues on this problem, but was unable to find any. I bet I am missing something, and my experience is that the more puzzling an issue is, the more obvious the mistake. But I really could use some pointers. Any thoughts? Thanks.

Jeroen

Comment: One way to make some progress on this would be to submit your code in a private ticket at http://support.cloudfoundry.com. We can post progress here. It's important to bind the service to the app, if we can see the code, we might be able to offer some pointers.

Comment: Another alternative might be to share the code with us on dropbox or github.

Comment: Ok thanks, I submitted a request at support.cloudfoundry.com

Comment: I appologize, I can't seem to find your ticket. Can you provide a pointer? Feel free to email.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the answer to your issue was because your code was missing a postgres service as well! The nullpointer exception in your case wasn't for the redis server you binded to your app but for the postgres server.

You have to be sure all the required services for your app are created and binded to the app.